# Button Bottom space showing different in different iPhone sizes in swift

Tags: swift, iphone, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

this is the design hierarchy in storyboard

[image]

here why `buy ticket button` bottom space varies for different screen sizes.

for buy ticket i have given bottom space to superview 90 like this

[image]

and for scrollview i have given like this

[image]

**now see the buy button bottom position for different screen sizes** please guide me to fix this issue

[image] [image] [image]

**EDIT:** buy button with safe area looks like this in smaller screen with home indicator.. where am i wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to be a floating button? I mean, is it supposed to move or not? Also, which view did you add it to? view or scrollView?

Comment: Why are you using a multiplier of 1.1 for scrollView?

Comment: @RobC, button should nt be move..so button is outside the scrollview... is there any difference using multiplier or constatnt value.. i have given multiplier because same design in all other storyboards

Comment: You should probably be constraining your button to the bottom safe area layout guide so that it will dynamically adjust to the different heights of tab bars on devices with and without a home indicator.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, for button bottom i didnt give safe area i have given superview.. then why showing difference

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, should i change button bottom to safe area?

Comment: You have a constraint that says the bottom of the button should have a space of 90 points to the bottom of the screen. But the tab bar has different heights on different devices. The safe area layout guide takes that into consideration. So instead of constraining to superview.bottom it needs to be constrained to the safe area layout guide (with a smaller constant).

Comment: Your next problem will be that the button obscures the scroll view (which fills the screen rather than being constrained to the top of the button). I think `contentInset` is a way to set an additional content inset to the bottom of the scroll view (equal to the height of the button and some padding) so that you will be able to scroll far enough to see the very bottom of the content. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset

Comment: Yeah, pin to the safe are and use the same constant.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, i have edited my post with button bottom to safe area.. but here screen with home indicator(small phone- iPhone8) looks like that added screen shot in post.. where am i wrong

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, however button is outside of scrollview

Comment: It looks correct in the storyboard (the bottom of the constraint is above the home indicator). Are you using a non-standard tab bar which is not properly setting the safe area? Or maybe you need to ensure layout margins are preserved down the view hierarchy? I’m away from my Mac but I think there’s some properties for controlling inheriting superview layout margins (and maybe safe area insets).